# Is totality a (large) cocompleteness condition?

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, 2-categories, universal-property

A locally small category $A$ is called [total](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/total+category) if its Yoneda embedding $A \to [A^\circ, \mathbf{Set}]$  has a left adjoint. Such categories are necessarily small-cocomplete (since the presheaf category contains, in particular, the small presheaves), but this is a stronger condition than small-cocompleteness in general.

It is natural to want to view totality as a cocompleteness condition. This is conceptually how totality is often introduced, and is justified to some extent by the following result of Kelly ([Theorem 5.3](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1986__27_2_109_0/)).

**Theorem (Kelly).** The following are equivalent for a locally small category $A$.

1. $A$ is total.
2. For each presheaf $\phi \colon A^\circ \to \mathbf{Set}$, $A$ admits the weighted colimit $\phi * 1_A$.
3. For each presheaf $\phi \colon K^\circ \to \mathbf{Set}$ and functor $d \colon K \to A$, $A$ admits the weighted colimit $\phi * d$ if and only if $\mathbf{Set}$ admits the weighted colimit $(\phi * d)(a, d{-})$  for each $a \in A$.

However, these conditions characterise total categories under a class of weights *and* diagrams; in other words, the colimits admitted by a total category $A$ are defined in terms of $A$. This is in contrast to free cocompletions, where we characterise colimits solely in terms of a class of weights.

**My question.** Is there a class $\Phi$ of weights such that the locally small $\Phi$-cocomplete categories are precisely the total categories?

Here, *weight* is simply defined to be a presheaf (if necessary, class-valued rather than set-valued), not necessarily with small domain. Such a $\Phi$, if it exists, will necessarily contain all small weights, and some large weights.

I would alternatively be happy with an explicit description of the universal property of the category of presheaves, in terms of a free cocompletion under small colimits together with some class of large colimits. In particular, I am predominantly wondering whether the presheaf construction on locally small categories forms a relative lax-idempotent pseudomonad.

(I suspect this question has a trivial answer, but for now I do not see whether it is trivially true or trivially false.)

Comment: I'd say kelly's results means the answer to the question in the title is yes. But which large colimits exists does not only depends on the weight, but also on the functor to A. The answer to the question you ask where things only depends on the weight is no.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure how to word the title precisely but concisely. Is it easy to see why the answer to the question is no? (Kelly shows that one can characterise the colimits as those depending on diagrams, but I do not see how to show from this that a presentation purely by weights is impossible.)

Comment: My "no" is based on the fact that I'm not  aware of a single exemple of an exemple of a weight $\Phi$ such that the corresponding colimits exists in all total categories, but not in all co-complete category. I think one can proove there is no such weight, but I'm struggling a bit finishing it...

Comment: One motivation for my question was discovering that the category of "petty presheaves" on a locally small category $C$ exhibited the "free well-cocompletion" of $C$ (Remark 4.39 of Lack–Tendas's [Virtual concepts in the theory of accessible categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.11056)), which looks like a large cocompletion, and is in particular contained in the category of presheaves on $C$.

Comment: One problem you'll have for this is that the presheaves category no longer have its covariant functoriality when moving to locally small categories.

Comment: I think if there's an obstruction to covariant functoriality, this would already be a refutation of my question, because then taking presheaves on locally small categories would not have a freeness property. I was wondering whether this was the case earlier, but I didn't see how to show it.

Comment: The answer here is somewhat foundation dependent, unless I miss something; do you have a preference of foundation? In particular, I believe the covariant functorality issue can be ameliorated by working in a foundation with multiple levels of large/small-ness for categories.

Comment: Following Lack and Tendas, it seems that any example of a presheaf $\phi$ which is petty but not small is an example of a weight such that total categories have all $\phi$-weighted colimits but cocomplete categories in general do not, answering the implicit question of @SimonHenry's [second comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444795/is-totality-a-large-cocompleteness-condition#comment1148616_444795). Unfortunately, I don't know an example of such a presheaf... what would be an example?

Comment: @AlecRhea: I'm happy to assume as many universes as necessary to make everything work out. "Small" and "large" can be read as with respect to some universe, rather than literally sets and classes if that addresses any technical issues.